# Game cannot sign into xbox live and shows placeholder text. Xbox live creators program

Tags: unity-game-engine, xbox-one, xbox-live

So I am making a game in `Unity` and added the Xbox live sign in prefab and set it up. In `Unity` It works fine however once I publish it to the store and load the game on my Xbox one, it is unable to sign me in and shows placeholder text.

I am using `unity 2017.3.1` to make the game and `visual studio 2017 community edition` to create app packages for the store. I have enabled Xbox live in my game in my dashboard and use the Xbox live association wizard in unity to set my game up.

Comment: Perhaps including your relevant code might help

Comment: i have not edited the code from the prefab you get with the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I would give the new version of the plugin a try (v1804). It uses a new 'PlayerAuthentication' prefab that handles authentication differently. You can find that release here: https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-unity-plugin/releases/tag/v1804